# What's the formula for the brightness of a signal mirror viewed at distance X, in space?

Tags: optics, reflection

What's the formula for the maximum brightness of a triangle-shaped, flat signal mirror G with area A in orbit radius O around star S with brightness B and diameter D viewed at distance X, in space, viewed at angle θ?

By maximum brightness I mean, the angle is whatever gives the max brightness.

I'm not looking for "apparent brightness" to the human eye, I'm looking for the actual optical brightness as could be measured with a sufficiently powerful detecting instrument.

Ideally the brightness could be given in watts (signal strength). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are not very useful, which might be why this question wasn't answered already despite being fairly straightforward.

We want the irradiance $E_e$ (in $W/m^2$) due to a perfect mirror at distance $r'$, angle $\theta '$ from the mirror.

The mirror has area $A$ and is at distance $r$, angle $\theta$ from the sun, such that its cross-sectional area with respect to the sun is $Asin(\theta).$

Assuming a flat mirror, $r >> \sqrt{A}$, and $r' >> \sqrt{A}$, we see no image at all unless $\theta ' = \theta$ (angle of receiver is the same angular distance from the normal line of the mirror as the sun, and on the opposite side thereof).

So we are looking for $E_e = f(r', r, A, \theta)$

Power of the sun at its surface is that of an ideal blackbody at the star's surface temperature T, given by the Stefan-Boltzmann Law.

$P = A_{sun}\sigma T^4$

where $\sigma = 5.67 \times 10^{-8}\frac{W}{m^2 K^4}$

Irradiance at a distance r is just power divided by the surface area of a sphere of the same radius:

$E_e = \frac{P}{4 \pi r'^2}$

The radiant flux (in Watts) through the mirror is the cross-sectional area of the mirror multiplied by the irradiance at its radius.

$\Phi_e = \frac{PAsin(\theta)}{4 \pi r^2}$

Assuming a perfect mirror the radiant flux is all reflected, so

$P_{mirror} = \Phi_e$

You can take it from here. Irradiance from the mirror at radius r' is..? For a receiver of cross-sectional area A' the radiant flux is..?